# Excel IF Statement with 4 conditions

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have drop down list in excel that when something from the drop down is selected the cell below displays a value.

I can get the following to work but when I try to add a fourth value it errors out.

What am I missing or need to do different?

```
=IF(B1="Report","Complete Report Section",IF(B1="HLE","Complete HLE Section",""))
```

I need to add a IF B1= Enhancement, Complete Enhancement section but for some reason I can not.

Comment: Did either of the formulas below work for you? If so please mark as correct. It is something only you can do. It will mark the question as answered. If they did not work, some feedback will help us help you.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is from a drop down and the only thing that changes is the second word.  Try this:

```
=IF(B1<>"", "Complete " & B1 & " Section")
```

If you want the big nasty formula:

```
=IF(B1="Report","Complete Report Section",IF(B1="HLE","Complete HLE Section",IF(B1="Enhancement","Complete Enhancement Section","")))
```